# QLabel becomes black instead of transparent

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, transparent

I have QLabel and I want to make it transparent(semi-transparent actually). The only thing that works for me is `setWindowOpacity(0.5)`. But it makes text transparent too.

I've tried:

1. `setStyleSheet("QWidget{background-color: transparent;}")`
2. `setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)")`
3. `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);`
4. `setAttribute( Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent, true );`

But window becomes black and i have no idea why. My os windows 10 x64.

Comment: Can you please show the main.cpp and / or .ui file?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Qt, but I think setBackgroundRole is what you're looking for.

Comment: i create 'widget' and call widget.show() in main.cpp. Nothing more

Comment: Alas, you can't make a semi-transparent widget with QSS only. QLabel can show text, inheriting background, but if I understood you right the goal is to make it colored, but semi-transparent. Maybe, you should place a simple QLabel on a widget, that had `setWindowOpacity(0.5)` set (didn't try myself).

Answer (score 2):

I added `this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);`
And now `this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);` works.